# How to delete the snooze from a snoozed email in Gmail to show it in the inbox category?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

I have a snoozed email and want to remove the snooze, having the email appear back in `Inbox`. How do I do this? I can't find any delete/remove snooze button.

Comment: Questions on applications or application features that are no longer available are off-topic for Web Applications as no one will ever be able to make use of the answers again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, found the `Pin to the Inbox` button. It does several things:

1. Removes the snooze.
2. Moves to Inbox.
3. Pins the letter.

I later remove the pin as I don't want it pinned - just in the inbox.

* Kind of hacky, but does the job. My theory for the lack of counter-snooze button is that the Pin has a too close functionality that they preferred to have one less button. Less clutter.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a counter-snooze button, but I would expect that when I click the snooze button on something that is already snoozed, I would get the option to unsnooze.

Answer (score 3):

I have the inbox setting on that separates unread emails from all the others. In that scenario I found a different way of doing it (which I confess I find counterintuitive).

If you click on a snoozed message to open it, there's a banner at the top with a "Dismiss" link which, when clicked, treats the message as though it were read and it disappears from the unread filter.

It would have made more sense to put the Dismiss feature in the same drop down as the rest of the snooze timings, and that's where I went looking for it.

Comment: Does it put the email back into the inbox?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's a new feature, but I've got an "Unsnooze" link when I open the message:

[image: Snooze message and unsnooze link.]

Comment: Interesting, but I don't currently see that. That would really make sense.

Comment: I've just checked again (snoozing a thread and then going to the Snoozed link on the left), and it still shows the Unsnooze link for me when I view the thread.  I can't see anything in my theme or the settings that would enable or disable this functionality...

Comment: Weird. I wonder why you're seeing it and I'm not. My snooze bar on the message is also orange rather than the gray in your screenshot.

Comment: Bizarre!  I have no idea.  I'm pretty sure I'm on the latest version of gmail but can't find anywhere that confirms that or allows me to revert to an older version.  It looks and works the same for me on both Firefox and Chromium.

Comment: When I select snoozed emails (in the Snoozed folder) and press the snooze button (which pops up default snooze durations) then there's also Unsnooze.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the unsnooze option exists only for those snoozed into the future. Those emails where the snoozed time is in the present, or in the past, do not have the unsnooze label.

Answer (score 0):

To take your question

> How to delete the snooze from a snoozed email in Google inbox?

literally, you can just "Mark done".

> [H]aving the email appear back in Inbox

can be achieved by "Pin to the inbox", as you have found out yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on email message, and then just click 'mute' - done